# Subset columns of a matrix by excluding all values of a vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector, subset

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
> expressionMatrix

        Sample_1  Sample_2  Sample_3  Sample_4  Sample_5
Gene_1         1         2         3         4         5     
Gene_2         6         7         8         9        10
```

And a vector:

```
outliers <- c("Sample_2",  "Sample_3")
```

If I ask for a subset of `expressionMatrix` that includes ONLY the samples in `outliers`, that works fine:

```
subset(expressionMatrix, select=outliers)

            Sample_2  Sample_3  
    Gene_          2         3 
    Gene_2         7         8
```

However, I can't seem to get the subset of `expressionMatrix` that includes all samples EXCEPT the ones in `outliers`.

I tried:

```
subset(expressionMatrix, select=-outliers)
```

but that returns an error:

```
Error in -(outliers) : invalid argument to unary operator
```

However, asking for the exclusion of the values in the vector (without quotes) directly *does* work:

```
subset(expressionMatrix, select=-c(Sample_2,  Sample_3))

        Sample_1   Sample_4  Sample_5
Gene_1         1          4         5     
Gene_2         6          9        10
```

I tried to do this to outliers by converting it to:

```
subset(expressionMatrix, select=-noquotes(outliers))
```

But still the same error.

```
Error in -noquote(outliers) : invalid argument to unary operator.
```

Why is the `subset` function accepting a vector object when asking for inclusion, but not when asking for exclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is a test object

```
expressionMatrix<-as.data.frame(matrix(1:10, nrow=2,
    dimnames=list(paste("Gene",1:2,sep="_"), 
    paste("Sample",1:5, sep="_"))))
```

Just as you don't put quotes around the columns in the `subset=` parameter of subset, you're meant to put unquoted names in the the `select=` parameter as well. The `subset` "magically" transforms the names into indexes so

```
select=-c(Sample_2,  Sample_3)
```

is transformed to

```
select=-c(2,3)
```

And you can index a data.frame with `dd[, -c(2,3)]` just fine. However, you have never been able to use the minus symbol with a character vector. "Netagive indexing" works only with integer values. And if you pass in a character vector to `select=`, because there are no free symbols, they aren't resolved to indexes. So you wind up with `dd[, -c("Sample_2",  "Sample_3")]` which doesn't work. (It will happen to work if you pass in `select=c("Sample_2",  "Sample_3")` because that's left "untranslated" and runs as `dd[, c("Sample_2",  "Sample_3")]` just fine). You could build the call in a messy way

```
outliers<-as.call(c(`c`, lapply(c("Sample_2","Sample_3"), as.name)))
do.call("subset", list(quote(expressionMatrix), select=outliers))
```

but if you really want to use strings, you can use the more traditional

```
outliers<-c("Sample_2","Sample_3")
expressionMatrix[, setdiff(names(expressionMatrix), outliers)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation.
I still don't understand why passing the argument as `select=-(noquote(outliers))` does not work. I am essentially passing `select=-c(Sample_2, Sample_3)` , aren't I?

Comment: @PinkSharpie - no, because `noquote()` creates a class "noquote" object, which is not the same as a class "name" object.  Underneath, the "noquote" object is still a character vector. Although I understand the confusion, they do look the same.

Comment: Plus the `select=` parameter is left for lazy evaluation. The "outliers" variable will not be expanded soon enough in the evaluation for that to work. The column names must explicitly appear in the parameter of the function in order to be expanded.

Comment: I see. I think I understand what is going on now. Thanks. And that ´setdiff´ expression is awesome.